# dplyr rowwise, find closest (latitude, longitude) record in a second data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, geocoding

Would like to assign each zip code to its closest ghcnd weather collection station.  Using `library(zipcode)` and the list of ghcnd stations available from NOAA (ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/)

Trying to use `dplyr`; using a `rowwise %>% mutate()`. All rows are assigned the same value from the lookup table.

```
#small selection of zip codes from library(zipcode)
zip_samp <- "zip latitude longitude
30002 33.77212 -84.26491
30003 33.96035 -84.03786
30004 34.11918 -84.30292
30005 34.08004 -84.21929
39885 31.71000 -84.34000
39886 31.73000 -84.60000
39897 30.90000 -84.32000
39901 33.89125 -84.07456
"
zip <- read.table(text=zip_samp, header=TRUE)

#two example stations
station_samp <- "id lat long
US1GADK0015 33.7794 -84.2572
US1GAGW0024 33.8885 -84.0998
"
stations <- read.table(text=station_samp, header=TRUE)
```

Illustrate desired output by hardcoding:

```
as.character(stations[which.min(distGeo(c(-84.26491, 33.77212), select(stations, long, lat))), "id"])
    [1] "US1GADK0015"

as.character(stations[which.min(distGeo(c(-84.07456, 33.89125), select(stations, long, lat))), "id"])
[1] "US1GAGW0024"
```

note these two zip codes are assigned to different station ids, but when the  same formula is applied rowwise with `dplyr`, all zip codes are assigned to a single ID.

```
assigned <- zip %>%
    select(longitude, latitude) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(station =
        as.character(stations[which.min(distGeo(., select(stations, long, lat))), "id"])
    )

print(assigned)
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  longitude latitude     station
      <dbl>    <dbl>       <chr>
1 -84.26491 33.77212 US1GADK0015
2 -84.03786 33.96035 US1GADK0015
3 -84.30292 34.11918 US1GADK0015
4 -84.21929 34.08004 US1GADK0015
5 -84.34000 31.71000 US1GADK0015
6 -84.60000 31.73000 US1GADK0015
7 -84.32000 30.90000 US1GADK0015
8 -84.07456 33.89125 US1GADK0015
```

Is there an alternative to indexing inside the `mutate()` call?

*note, trying to avoid creating the entire distance matrix at once.  I hope computing rowwise will require fewer resources*

Also, there are a couple similar questions on SO, none using `dplyr` though. Hoping to figure why this application of rowwise %>% mutate isnt producing the expected results.

Comment: Hey! Since I'm assuming t worked (given the ✅) can you confirm if it went abt 2-3 minutes as I guesstimated? (I'm just curious)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Ran quicker than 3 minutes, but I'm on an enterprise rStudio server, so YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you (an eyeball of the data says it does):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)
library(zipcode)

stat_df <- read_fwf(
  "ghcnd-stations.txt", 
  fwf_widths(widths=c(11, 1, 8, 1, 9, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 30, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5))
)

stations <- select(stat_df, station_id = X1, latitude = X3, longitude = X5)

closest_station <- function(lat, lon) {
  index <- which.min(sqrt((stations$latitude-lat)^2 + (stations$longitude-lon)^2)) # less precise but likely good enough
  stations[index,]$station_id
}

data(zipcode)
zipcode <- tbl_df(zipcode)

zipcode

set.seed(1492)
smpl <- zipcode[sample(nrow(zipcode), 100),]

mutate(smpl, station_id = map2_chr(latitude, longitude, closest_station))
## # A tibble: 100 x 6
##      zip              city state latitude  longitude  station_id
##    <chr>             <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <chr>
##  1 28137         Richfield    NC 35.49326  -80.25524 US1NCSN0006
##  2 22027       Dunn Loring    VA 38.89392  -77.21976 US1VAFX0064
##  3 19080             Wayne    PA 40.04320  -75.35768 US1PADL0005
##  4 12459      New Kingston    NY 42.22799  -74.68912 USC00305743
##  5 06082           Enfield    CT 41.98724  -72.56365 US1CTHR0005
##  6 01302        Greenfield    MA 42.52218  -72.62416 USC00193295
##  7 83540            Lapwai    ID 46.39708 -116.78649 USC00105132
##  8 49266             Osseo    MI 41.84489  -84.55244 USC00203823
##  9 37871 Strawberry Plains    TN 36.04051  -83.67934 USC00408677
## 10 75042           Garland    TX 32.91562  -96.67399 US1TXDA0065
## # ... with 90 more rows
```

I think this math is right but have to jet…

```
microbenchmark(mutate(smpl, station_id = map2_chr(latitude, longitude, closest_station)))
# !300ms for 100
# ((nrow(zipcode)/100) * 300) / 1000 / 60 == ~3m
```